# Order by different column if results are the same

Tags: mysql

Basically, if two people have the same score in my game, the person who is in the first position on the leaderboard is whichever score / record is the newest.

How can I change my query so that if two or more people have the same score, it then sorts by name alphabetically and puts that score on the top. My query is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY Score DESC");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order by both in preference order;

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY Score DESC, Name ASC
```